# Dell Laptop Booting Problem (wondering if anyone else has had it)

Tags: laptop, power

I have a problem getting the lap top to start up after changing memory cards.

1. The new memory was correct for the laptop as per Crucial identifier..
2. Removal and installation was done according to normal i.e. removal of battery, pressing start button to discharge the machine before opening the flap covering the memory and the new modules were fitted correctly. I then ran into a boot up problem.
3. After replacing the battery and switching the machine on the green power on light came on, the disk indicator light came on.  On the left hand side of the on switch are five indicator lights and one of these a green light depicting a bag with the letter “A” came on.   After a few seconds the machine powered down.
4. I repeated the procedure with the machine connected charger which was switched on.   Again the boot up went through the same procedure as 3) above.
5. I took out the new memory and re-inserted the old memory but the same problem occurred.  I cannot access the DVD drive either.
6. I have confirmed that the power supply light on the laptop does not come on (using chargers that I know are working) regardless of whether the battery is installed or not.

Has anyone else experience this and how did you overcome it

Comment: You might consider posting the exact model of laptop you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was resolved by someone pushing the memory in HARD (much harder than I would normally push it in). Maybe it's a Dell thing?

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the answer.